# RestEasyProviderFactory ClassCastException in openstack4j

Tags: java, openstack, openstack-swift, openstack4j

I have upgraded my version of openstack4j to the 3.0.3 (from v2) and I'm having this error when running it from Tomcat with both OKHTTP Connector and HTTPCLIENT Connector.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:353)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor.checkClientExceptionMapper(ApacheHttpClient4Executor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor.<init>(ApacheHttpClient4Executor.java:126)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.resteasy.executors.ApacheHttpClientExecutor.<init>(ApacheHttpClientExecutor.java:24)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.resteasy.executors.ApacheHttpClientExecutor.create(ApacheHttpClientExecutor.java:48)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.resteasy.HttpCommand.initialize(HttpCommand.java:43)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.resteasy.HttpCommand.create(HttpCommand.java:37)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.resteasy.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invoke(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:51)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.resteasy.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:30)
    at org.openstack4j.core.transport.internal.HttpExecutor.execute(HttpExecutor.java:51)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.OSAuthenticator.authenticateV3(OSAuthenticator.java:154)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.OSAuthenticator.invoke(OSAuthenticator.java:70)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.client.OSClientBuilder$ClientV3.authenticate(OSClientBuilder.java:165)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.client.OSClientBuilder$ClientV3.authenticate(OSClientBuilder.java:128)
```

This problem didn't occur with v2 of openstack4j.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using version 3.0.4 on my maven project.
Upgrading the dependency to 3.1.0 one solved it.
Here is the included artifact details:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.pacesys</groupId>
   <artifactId>openstack4j</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```